# BUYING BUNNY WITH ETH.... Etherscan showing "dropped?" Don't know what to do

Tags: transactions, ether, etherscan, pending-transactions

To preface, I'm crypto dumb except for buying /selling BTC. I don't mess with Alt coins much... and this issue is why!!!! HELP!!!

So I tried to acquire some BUNNY with ETH on Uniswap. I checked it this morning and the status says "dropped." What do I do?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xda57edfc9e5e69b219763b5194dfe255aa1d3b62da88a87a5a9303bfb29538e7

Comment: Since gas price is too low, you might cancel or send a new tx with higher gas price: https://info.etherscan.com/how-to-cancel-ethereum-pending-transactions/#replacing-cancel-pending-transactions

Answer (score 1):

after looking at the transaction on etherscan it appears the gas fee you provided appears to be too low (5GWei).

The current state of ethereum is very congested, therefore user's must bid to get their transactions processed. This is done through the setting of the gas price. The higher the gas price the faster your transaction will be included in a new block.

At the time of writing, https://www.gasnow.org/ quotes the "slow time" for processing to be around 140 GWei. I know this price is exceptionally high and may act as a deterrent for you using the network at this time.

My advice would be: if you can afford it, submit the transaction again at a higher gas price. By looking at gasnow.org you can get an idea of what gas price will allow a transaction to be processed at what time. You may have to wait a while, or you may get lucky and the gasprice dip to an acceptable level for you in the next few days.